# How to change the icon in the title bar in R?

Tags: user-interface, r, statistics, icons, titlebar

I just installed R 2.11.0-x64 onto my Windows 7 Professional machine.

With my previous installations of R (2.10.1 32 bit was the most recent) the little icon that appeared in the title bar and in the taskbar at the bottom of windows was the R "R."  Now however, the icon almost looks like a small windows Task Manager.

I know this isn't a code issue, but it affects me as I flip between windows.

Is there a way to put the "R" icon back in there?  Would it be an R setting or a Windows setting?

Comment: This question should probably be on superuser.com.

Comment: I never used super user but am familiar with stackoverflow so I put it forward here.

Sorry for it being out of place, but I'm hoping someone here knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug that was fixed yesterday.  As per [this Daily R Devel News entry post](http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/2010/04/24#c2010-04-24):

> 2.11.0 patched NEW FEATURES (Windows)
>
> ```
> * The Rgui console, pagers and editor on the 64-bit build now have a 
>   title bar icon.
> ```

So upgrading to the '2.11.0 patched' build may help.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I may be a little slow on this, but I can only find the patched version for 32-bit (http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html) but not for 64-bit (http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows64/base/).

I redownload the 64-bit installer, but it seems to be the same as the old one.